# Cannot run an android code on Processing

Tags: android, processing

When I try to run an android code in Processing 2.2.1 Android mode I get the following message:

```
Error from inside the Android tools, check the console.
```

And then:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Processing\modes\AndroidMode\icons\icon-96.png (The system cannot locate the resource specified) 
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at processing.app.Base.copyFile(Base.java:2698)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidBuild.writeRes(AndroidBuild.java:807)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidBuild.createProject(AndroidBuild.java:169)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidBuild.build(AndroidBuild.java:91)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidMode.handleRunDevice(AndroidMode.java:227)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidEditor$16.run(AndroidEditor.java:513)

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\android9132488509980035650sketch\build.xml:9: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

What can I do to solve it? I am a total beginner so please try to be as specific and clear as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: the error pretty clearly indicates that you're missing an icon, and even tells you which one.

Answer (score 0):

Program wants this file "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Processing\modes\AndroidMode\icons\icon-96.png" and cannot find it.